# <noscript> css works after 2 browser refreshes only

Tags: javascript, css, html, noscript

My  tags only take affect when javascript is disabled hence that is what it should do, my issue is:

If I disable javascript, and I refresh the my website page I am on, I only get the following:

[image]

Then if I refresh the browser for a second time, it works and I get the following:

[image]

I am using the stackoverflow one as a example but mine looks the exact same when refreshed for a second time.

If i close my browser open it, disable javascript, then open my website, it works the first time.

Is this a cache issue? it seems a bit unusual to only take affect after the second refresh.

My Code:

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <style>
    .js-msg {
        font-weight:bold;
        background-color:#c90000;
        padding-top:5px;
        padding-bottom:5px;
        font-size:18px;
        color:#ffffff;
        position:fixed;
        z-index:1000;
        text-align:center;
        width:100%;
    }
    </style>
    <body>
       <noscript>
            <div class="js-msg">
                Our forms work best with Javascript enabled.
            </div>
        </noscript>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle to demonstrate the problem... oh... nevermind.

Comment: I think this could be a cache issue, in Chrome when you inspect an element you can click on the cog (top right) and choose "disable cache when dev tools open" this might help you diagnose the problem.

Comment: true ill try that, it is weird because stackoverflow does not need to refresh twice on my end, it always works the first time which has got me puzzled

Comment: Many browsers have an Empty Cache option which can be activated by hitting control/command + shift + backspace. Do that first and I also use Web Developer Tools which lets you Disable/Disable JavaScript/Disable All JavaScript.

Comment: Okay after disabling cache in the dev tools it worked first time perfectly :) thank you!